# how to predict how long it will take for python to run a script?

Tags: python, function, time, pickle

So I want to make sure that I run my program when it is optimal, for example, if it will take 5 hours to complete, I should run it overnight!

I do know this program will end, and theoretically I should be able to base length on size. So here is the actual problem:

I need to open 16 pickled files that are pandas DataFrames that add up to a total of 1.5 gigs. Note, I will also need to do this with DataFrames that add up to 20 gigs, so the answer I need is a way of telling how long the following code will take given total amounts of gigs:

```
import pickle
import os
def pickleSave(data, pickleFile):
    output = open(pickleFile, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(data, output)
    output.close()
    print "file has been saved to %s" % (pickleFile)
def pickleLoad(pickleFile):
    pkl_file = open(pickleFile, 'rb')
    data = pickle.load(pkl_file)
    pkl_file.close()
    return data
directory = '/Users/ryansaxe/Desktop/kaggle_parkinsons/GPS/'
files = os.listdir(directory)
dfs = [pickleLoad(directory + i) for i in files]
new_file = directory + 'new_file_dataframe'
pickleSave(dfs,new_file)
```

so now I need to write a function that will look like the following:

```
def time_fun(data_size_in_gigs):
    #some algorithm here
    print "your code will take ___ hours to run"
```

I have no clue how to approach this, or if it is even possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Before anyone chimes in with the halting problem, let's assume we're only interested in getting a likely-correct approximation for programs that do halt.

Comment: exactly! thank you I should have mentioned that

Comment: Have you tried running it on a smaller subset of the data?

Comment: yes, I have been using this data for weeks. But I need to be able to predict time for any amount of gigs so I can optimize my time. It is also just a very useful function for anybody using python

Comment: I'm not sure how pandas deals with large dataframes, but assuming a 20GB dataframe doesn't fit into memory (but, e.g., a 1.5GB dataframe, or a small subset, does), swapping will make any extrapolation very non-linear, thus making things very unpredictable. Though if someone knows how to handle/estimate that, I'd love to hear as well.

Comment: exactly! 20GB is a bit overkill, but that's my point! after a while things slow down exponentially and I would like to be able to predict that with some accuracy

Comment: have you formally expressed the big-o complexity of your algorithm ? if so, with a few samples, you can interpolate the parameters of your time function.

Comment: i am not familiar with that wording? big-o complexity?

Comment: From your code it would seem that only thing you do is unpickle from individual files and pickle to one big file. Is that correct?

Comment: this is a quicker version of what I will be doing. I will be editing the dataframes and adding some columns and changing some values before saving into one bigger file. But essentially yes I unpickle and then pickle

Answer (score 3):

This execution time is entirely dependent on your system, i.e., hard drive / SSD, processor, etc. No one can tell you upfront what time it will take to run on YOUR computer, the only way you'll be able to get a precise estimate will be to run your script on sample files that add up to a small size such as 100mb, take note of how long it took, and base your estimations off of that.

```
def time_fun(data_size_in_gigs):
    benchmark = time_you_manually_tested_for_100mb
    time_to_run = data_size_in_gigs/0.1 * benchmark
    print "your code will take time_to_run hours to run"
```

**Edit:** In fact, you may want to save this benchmark (size,time) pair on a file, to which you also automatically add new entries whenever you actually run your script. Here in your function, you may for example want to retrieve the 2 benchmarks that are closest to the data_size you're currently estimating, and estimate off of them, just taking the average and making it proportional to the `data_size` you need. Each adjacent pair of benchmarks will define a different linear slope which will be the most accurate to data near it.

```
     |                  .
     |                 .
time |               .
     |            .
     |       .
     |_._________________
              size
```

Just avoid saving 2 benchmarks that differ by less than 200mb for example, as the actual time may vary and could ruin your estimation with entries such as (999mb, 100 minutes) followed by (1gb, 95 minutes).

The projection of the line defined by the 2 last points will be the closest estimate you have for new all-time-high data sizes.

Comment: this is a good point, and probably the best one I will get, but when dealing with lets say a 4GB dataframe, it is in no sense going to have a linear representation from the 100MB file.

Comment: you are assuming the time is linear to data size.

Comment: Which then again only leaves you two choices, either also time it once or twice with huge data, and base your model off of all benchmarks, or repeat the 100mb test while severely limiting the amount of RAM you allow Python to use, to ensure it all fits in ram. One way or the other, it will not be possible to estimate the time spent by future executions without prior benchmark of how your system performs, otherwise the estimation of the code would output the same time regardless of the computer it is on, which is obviously flawed.